# how to prevent postback by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**actually this code is working well in firefox mozilla but it's not working in IE8**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnPrimary" OnClientClick="return doSubmit('this');"
        OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
           function doSubmit() 
           {
            var ansLength = oDOM.body.innerText.trim().length;
            if (ansLength == 0 && smielyPresent == -1) 
              {
              alert("you cannot submit blank answer");
              return false;
              }
           }
    </script>

     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // i am doing some stuff
    }
```

here i want to prevent postback when `answerlength == 0 ;` 
but when `answer length ==0` then it alert  `alert("u can't submit blank answer")` message and postback to server io want to prevent it how i do ?

Comment: Missing ";" .. alert("u can't submit blank answer")

Comment: it's not workin wven showing message it's going for postback.

Comment: actually this is working in firfox mozila but it's not working in IE8

Comment: yaa this is shown in IE8 after that it's going to postback .

Comment: Return false works in IE8. I have tried it myself. To narrow down the issue can you remove the OnClick and see whether it still postbacks or have your return false out of the if clause and see the behaviour

Comment: when i remove onclick then it still goes to server (postback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working since you have a script error in your javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit() 
    {
        //I've removed the first equal sign
        var ansLength = oDOM.body.innerText.trim().length; 
        if (ansLength == 0 && smielyPresent == -1) //typo on smielyPresent ?
        {
            alert("u can't submit blank answer")
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: actually my question is right i have added by mistake var= ansLength = oDOM.body.innerText.trim().length; so can u check once again

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
OnClientClick="doSubmit(this); return false;"
```

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure. However, in a project I was working, when the return false was outside as above, then the post back was triggered. It was triggered in other cases. I really could not make out why this behaviour was observed. The OnClientClick was on image button.